# 24h screensaver - how to handle huge video

Tags: windows, video, vimeo, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I'm tasked with creating a windows screensaver that display a 24h video.

The original 24h HD video is 180GB

### As I see it there are 2 strategies

**Caching**

I could split the video into smaller parts (eg 10 min) and upload them to eg an Azure Storage Blob container. 
When a new video part was needed the screensaver could download the video to the local computer and play it from there.

This would over time cause the entire 180GB to be downloaded to the users harddrive.

**Streaming - DYI**

The 180GB file is uploaded to an Azure Storage Blob container. When the screensaver is active it is streaming from that uploaded file.

This would cause a lot of network traffic - and since no caching is involved, the traffic will occur all the time

### *Am I missing a obvious third strategy?*

---

**Compression**

Since the is not requirement for the video to be served in HD it's still a huge video file, even though I change it from HD to SD.

A helper in this field could be to use Vimeo (or the like) to host the file and handle the compression.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Have you checked out the Aerial project on GitHub? It works a whole lot like what you describe and intend to build out (downloading and locally caching videos for a screensaver): https://github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial

Comment: yes - i've used it with success. But it doesn't solve my strategy issue